# Compiler confused about composable record

Tags: elm

Given these type aliases

```
type alias Point =
    { x : Float
    , y : Float
    }

type alias ShapeProperties =
    { p1 : Point
    , p2 : Point
    }


type alias FillProperties a =
    { a | fill : Bool }


type alias FillShapeProperties =
    FillProperties ShapeProperties
```

and these functions

```
test1 : FillShapeProperties → Bool
test1 properties =
    if properties.p1.x == 0 then
        properties.fill
    else
        False

test2 : FillShapeProperties → Bool
test2 properties =
    if originX properties == 0 then
→         properties.fill
    else
        False

originX : ShapeProperties → Float
originX shape = 
    Basics.min shape.p1.x shape.p2.x
```

`test1` compiles but `test2` does not

The error message:

```
`properties` is being used in an unexpected way.

222|         properties.fill
             ^^^^^^^^^^
Based on its definition, `properties` has this type:

    { p1 : ..., p2 : ... }

But you are trying to use it as:

    { b | fill : ... }
```

In the definition of `test2` I'm clearly saying it's a `FillShapeProperties` so it should know it's a `{ p1 : ..., p2 : ..., fill: ... }`, no? In `test1` it knows...

It has something to do with the use of `originX` in `test2` and the fact it's being used as a simple `ShapeProperties` there. So what's going on here and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FillShapeProperties` is not the same record type as `ShapeProperties` even though they share common fields.

If you expand the definition of `FillShapeProperties`, it is equivalent to this:

```elm
type alias FillShapeProperties =
    { p1 : Point
    , p2 : Point
    , fill : Bool
    }
```

If you want to make your code a little more generic, you could make an alias for anything "like a shape":

```elm
type alias ShapeLike a =
    { a
        | p1 : Point
        , p2 : Point
    }
```

You could then change the signature of `originX` to accept `ShapeLike a` and your example will compile just fine:

```elm
originX : ShapeLike a -> Float
originX shape = 
    Basics.min shape.p1.x shape.p2.x
```